# Line Break within echo in a while loop

Tags: php, loops, echo, while-loop, line-breaks

Quick question, again, I'm sure this is ridiculously simple but I don't see what I'm doing wrong!

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))

{
echo  "<a href=\"http://mysite.com/{$row['row1']}/{$row['row2']} \">{$row['row3']} </a>";
}
```

This produces all my links to be stacked up one after the other. I want to order them in a list so I have tried:

```
echo "<ul>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))

{
echo  "<li><a href=\"http://mysite.com/{$row['row1']}/{$row['row2']} \">{$row['row3']}    </a> </li>";
}
echo "</ul>" ;
```

and

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))

{
echo  "<a href=\"http://mysite.com/{$row['row1']}/{$row['row2']} \">{$row['row3']}    </a> <br />";
}
```

The ultimate result I wish to see is :
-Link 1
-Link 2
-Link 3
-Link 4
What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your second example looks fine. Can you show us the resulting HTML output?

Comment: can you give an output how would like it to display?

Comment: I basically just want it to look like 
-Link 1
-Link 2
-Link 3
etc.
as for HTML output, what it does right now is just a succesion of <a href"mysite.com>site name</a><a href"mysite.com>site name</a><a href"mysite.com>site name</a> etc, with all attempts to line break or list them failing!

Comment: Sorry I thought hitting enter between each -Link 1 -Link 2 etc would work but it should be -Link 1 <br/> -Link 2 <br/> -Link3 <br/> etc.!

Comment: Your second example *really* looks fine. Can you check the HTML source of the output to make sure the `<li>`s are really there?

Comment: Weirdly, the tags disapear, however I can see the effects of <br/> tags when I view the source. In the source, the links all have a linebreak and are thus presented on top of each other like in my example, but there is no trace of the actual tag. Testing it elsewhere prooved that the initial code was just fine, but something is stripping the tags away for some reason. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For a line break in HTML try using `<br />`, your code can look like something along this line:

```
echo "<ul>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))

{ 
echo  "<li><a href=\"http://mysite.com/{$row['row1']}/{$row['row2']} \">{$row['row3']}</a></li> <br />";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

#### EDIT

Also note, as mentioned before in the comments, `<br />` isn't needed, if I take it out of my code my output stays the same.

I made a test php file similar and used my suggestion above and works fine, here is my code

```
<?php
echo "<ul>";
$i = 0;
do {
$i++;
echo  "<li><a href=\"http://mysite.com/{$i}/{$i} \">{$i}</a></li> <br />";
} while($i < 10);
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Displayed below:

[image: See]

Comment: Not downvoting, but when using `<ul><li>...</li><li></li></ul>` you should not be needing a `<br />` in there.

Comment: `<li>` doesn't make sense in this context (and is invalid without `<ul>` or `<ol>`)

Comment: Of course it makes sense: It's a *list* of links, so `<li>` (within `<ul>` or `<ol>`) is the *only* semantically correct way to write this.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I edited my original post, I didn't mean to have a <li> in the 3rd example, as I had tried that one simply as a <br/>, seeing that the <ul><li></li></ul> option had no effect!

Comment: Should I use <li> AND a <br/>?

Comment: @aforloney - I think you're missing the intention of the curly brackets in this case

Comment: I am trying an example code right now using <li> and <br /> and either or works just fine for me

Comment: @Marek K - I wouldn't doubt it, didn't think before I edited.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I also did a test in a different section, they both work fine. I was trying to do this in a Joomla module, there is probably something stripping away these tags.

Answer (score 0):

I can't spot anything wrong with it. Even a `<br/>` should work:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo  "<a href=\"http://mysite.com/{$row['row1']}/{$row['row2']} \">{$row['row3']} </a><br/>";
}
```

Comment: Oops sorry, that's what my third example should have been. I did try this as well, and still to no avail. What's extra weird to know, if this can help, is that when I look view-source this region of my page, adding the <br /> has an effect on my source's alignment of the links. Basically, instead of seeing a <br/> tag, I see its effect being applied into the source, creating the wanted lien break but not visible on the site itself?!

Answer (score 0):

use `echo "<a href="…>link</a>\n` to add a newline in the generated sourcecode

Comment: Tried that, to no avail either :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$layout .= "<div style='display:block;'><a href=\"http://mysite.com/{$row['row1']}/{$row['row2']} \">{$row['row3']}</a></div>";
}

echo $layout;
```

Comment: Very nice idea, still no result. It actually stacks up all my links without even a space in between them!

Comment: I am still confused how you like to display the result.